# What is causing n-gon to have smooth shading with unexisting bevel weight?

Tags: modifiers, faces, bevel

I accidently found that Bevel modifier with weight option somehow improves n-gon after subsurfing, but don't understand what does it actually do. There is no real bevel weight applied to the edge.

Decimate modifier draws same amount of faces either Bevel is turn or off. Normals also behave similiar, but shading is smoother. 
[image]

File to play with:
[image]

Comment: It maybe a problem caused by the non correct update of vertex normals. By the way it's not strictly related to the Bevel modifier, you can for example force the update by switching to edit mode (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujZZF.gif) or use another modifier that interact with the faces (wireframe, simple deform with zero factor, triangulate...)

Comment: Can you check whether in the Mesh Tab under Normals "Auto Smoothing" is active?

Comment: `Auto Smooth` is "Off"

Comment: I think Carlo is right, I played with that creased edge that you have around the top and when I push its crease value back to -1, it behaves like it should at 0. My guess is, that somewhere along the way, these value get overwritten.